# Laravel Mailing Dark Mode changing IMG

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, mode

Does anybody know how I can change an image based on the system preferences of the user when sending a email/notification in Laravel (PHP)?

For example I have a logo in my header.blade.php and I want to use the logoWhite when the system preferences of the user is in dark mode. I tried using Tailwind classes such ass dark: ... but it doesn't work.. :(

```
<img class="logo" alt="" id="logoImage" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,......" />
<img class="logoWhite" alt="" id="logoImage" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGR....."/>
```